# WHM and Domain name provider custom name server setup

Tags: dns, nameserver

- I have a domain address registered on Google. (For ex. `www.examp.tld` )
- I have a Reseller Hosting on `www.examp.tld`.
- I have Dedicated IP address for my own WHM.

What I want to do is set the custom name server addresses like `ns1.example.tld` and `ns2.example.tld`.

---

**Now:** My hosting provider gave me the following

[image]

```
ns1.provider.net -> 5.***.241.34
ns2.provider.net -> 5.***.242.34
```

But my permanent IP address in cPanel looks like this:

[image]

```
5.***.252.52
```

---

#### First of all, I made my Google settings as follows

[image]

[image]

#### My Main Account CPanel DNS Records as follows

[image]

---

My hosting provider asked me to adjust these settings. But what I can't understand is why we prefer a shared IP address rather than my own IP address. So why did we pay the extra fee and get Custom IP?

- **Q(1):** Are the IPv4 addresses that I will enter into Google domains correct? Or will I enter the IP address of "`5.***.252.52`" for both?
- **Q(2):** Are the "**A**" records in my main CPanel account correct? Or will I enter my own IP address "`5.***.252.52`" for it?
- **Q(3):** If they need to enter the IP address of the hosting provider (as in the photos), doesn't that cause my sites to be listed in the SHARED IP by search engines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be different IP addresses for your website and your nameserver,. this is not at all unusual.

The nameserver is where DNS settings are located.  Within DNS you may have an A record  pointing to a completely different IP address, where your website hosting is located.

**Q1** - you should use the ip addresses for `ns1.provider.net` and `ns1.provider.net` for your custom nameservers.

**Q2** - The A Record should be your dedicated IP address, assuming that is the IP address of your website hosting.

**Q3** - Do search engines even care about IP addresses?  I am no SEO expert, but as far as I know, they are only interested in the domain name.  Think about it, some IP addresses likely have thousands of domains on them, so what?

Comment: What you said made a lot of sense. Then I think the settings I made in the photos are correct. Thanks.